# Rust PyO3 - How to execute a script with unknown module imports?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I would like to execute a function in a Python module using Rust.
This module can have imports, which are unknown at programming time.

Example of a file to be run:

```py
import testmod

def main():
    print("Hello World!")
    testmod.test_fun()
    return 0
```

I would like a way to pass a file to PyO3 and have it resolve and import all the dependencies specified in the file. It seems like something that should be in the PyO3 package, but I could not find any documentation online.

Right now I am using this code, which does not work because the Python modules are not executing according to their dependency relationships:

```rust
pub fn python(args: &WatchCommand) -> PyResult<()> {
    let main = std::fs::canonicalize(&args.main)?;
    let parent = main.parent().unwrap();
    debug!("Loading Python Module...");
    // Load file contents
    let file_contents = std::fs::read_to_string(&args.main)?;
    // Run Python Code
    Python::with_gil(|py| -> PyResult<()> {
        // Load modules in the same folder
        debug!("Search Folder: {:?}", parent);
        for entry in WalkDir::new(&parent) {
            match entry {
                Ok(res) => {
                    if res.path().is_file() && res.path().extension().unwrap_or_default() == "py" {
                        debug!("Loading module: {:?}", res.path());
                        let file_content = std::fs::read_to_string(res.path())?;
                        let name = res.path().file_stem().unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
                        PyModule::from_code(py, &file_content, name, name)?;
                    }
                }
                Err(e) => error!("Error loading module: {}", e),
            }
        }
        let main = PyModule::from_code(py, &file_contents, "main.py", "main");
        // Build arguments
        let args = ();
        // let kwargs = [("slope", 0.2)].into_py_dict(py);clap
        let result: i16 = main?.getattr("main")?.call(args, None)?.extract()?;
        Ok(())
    })
}
```

This results in the following output:

```
DEBUG Loading Python Module...
DEBUG Search Folder: "..."
DEBUG Loading module: "...\main.py"
ERROR Error running python code: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testmod'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Riccardo

Comment: Have you tried to set the filename to the full path?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, the ellipse in the output was just to remove clutter from the question. Paths are absolute, and there are no IO errors.

Comment: i modified the script and ran it but i think i am having an issue with my linux compiler linking , i don't know if it will work at your side without any errors

Comment: There's nothing for pyo3 to support? Your import goes through the normal import machinery which is based off of the PYTHONPATH (and possibly import hooks). It's up to you to set the PYTHONPATH (or `sys.path`) correctly.